# NAudio multiple WaveOut objects

Tags: naudio

Currently I am constructing a synthesizer. i am wondering if there is anyway of having multiple waveOut() objects due to me wanting my synth to be polyphonic (multiple keys pressed at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

You should not open multiple WaveOut objects. Instead, create a mixer using `MixingSampleProvider` to sum together the outputs of all your synth's voices. It allows inputs to be dynamically added and automatically removes them when they finish. You need to configure it to produce an endless stream of silence if there are no inputs, or WaveOut will assume there is nothing more to play and stop automatically.

Comment: Thanks Mark Heath, wondering if there are any examples using MixingSampleProvider ? kind regards

Comment: In the NAudioWPF demo code, there is a drum machine example that uses it.

Comment: I have just checked the source code and it kind of scared me ! currently my program creates a sine wave using a Wave Stream , and when a key is pressed it plays it using WaveOut(). how will i go about reading my waveStream object  in MixingSampleProvider. sorry for the overload in questions, kind regards

Comment: your sine wave provider should implement ISampleProvider. Then it can be an input to MixingSampleProvider. Finally, use SampleToWaveProvider to pass the mixer to WaveOut